# How can I get any specific process window size?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried this in top of form1

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string strClassName, string strWindowName);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hwnd, ref Rect1 rectangle);

public struct Rect1
{
    public int Left { get; set; }
    public int Top { get; set; }
    public int Right { get; set; }
    public int Bottom { get; set; }
}
```

Then in constructor

```
Process[] processes1 = Process.GetProcessesByName("mspaint");
Process lol = processes1[0];
IntPtr ptr = lol.MainWindowHandle;
Rect1 mspaintRect = new Rect1();
GetWindowRect(ptr, ref mspaintRect);
```

But the result is strange I think.
In `mspainRect` using a break point I see

```
Bottom = -31972
Left = -32000
Right = -31840
Top = -32000
```

Comment: http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/IsIconic.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a window is minimized the location of windows is `{X=-32000,Y=-32000}`. So it seems in your example case, window of `mspaint` is minimized.

The reason behind this strange coordinates is because of backward compatibility with some old versions of Windows.

> [Where did windows minimize to before the taskbar was invented?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20041028-00/?p=37453/)
>
> Windows NT stuck with the -32000 coordinates and didn’t pick up the
> compatibility fixes for some reason. I guess they figured that by the
> time Windows NT became popular, all those broken programs would have
> been fixed.